# How to get the content of a table cell with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, datatables

When I hover over a table cell there appears a edit link right next to the content. I want to get that cell's content. Is is possible with jQuery?

The HTML page is this: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/4721230

Part of the table, which is generated by JavaScript. https://gist.github.com/anonymous/4721245

Comment: Can you post the inner html of that td?

Comment: @DonatasOlsevičius, it is created by fetching JSON data from a remote server. http://www.datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/server_side/server_side.html

Comment: I can't see any edit links in that example. Can you show your working version online or just paste the generated td html?

Comment: @DonatasOlsevičius, I have added the codes to Gist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a possible solution - [Here the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HmgBW/2/)

**js code**

```
var table = $('#tblFollow');


table.dataTable({
    sDom: "t",
    aoColumns: [
      null,
      null,
      { bSortable: false }
    ]
});



table.on('click', 'a', function(e){
    var followingCell = $(this).parents('td').prev();
    var rowIndex = table.fnGetPosition( $(this).closest('tr')[0] );
    var aData = table.fnGetData( rowIndex  );
    alert (aData[0] + " / " + aData[1]+ " / " + aData[2]);

    return false;
});
```

**html code**

```
<table id="tblFollow">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>id</th>
            <th>name</th>
            <th>link</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>John</td>

            <td><a  href="#">Link</a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>Bill</td>

            <td><a  href="#">Link</a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>Anna</td>

            <td><a  href="#">Link</a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>4</td>
            <td>Dick</td>
            <td><a  href="#">Link</a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>5</td>
            <td>Jane</td>

            <td><a href="#">Link</a></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: This is the exact thing that I want but it didn't work because I think the link is generated when I hover over the cell and thus the click event cannot attach itself to the link. http://i.imgur.com/iO3YRx7.png .

Comment: show your code , try to inspect the `event` object , `event.target` find a way to get the connection between the link and its source caller

Comment: This worked `$(this).parents('td').next().next().next().next().next().next()[0].innerHTML`

Comment: it looks like you could use some better selector , try to assign some `class` to that `....next()[0]` and use it `$(this).parents('td .someClass')[0].innerHTML`

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely.

```
<table id="this_is_the_one">
 <tbody>
  <tr>
   <td>
     content 1
   </td>
   <td>
     content 2
   </td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>

<script type="text/javascript">
$('#this_is_the_one td').on('click', function() {
  alert($(this).html());
  //$(this) returns the <td> element being pressed
});
</script>
```

In case you have formatting code (HTML) in the table cells and you don't want them to show up, you could also take the HTML and [display it in a dialog box](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/), or you could (when the table is being generated in a PHP script) add attributes to the  with the plain content and use $(elem).prop(prop-name) function to get the value of that property.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it so:

```
$("#test td").on("mouseover",function(){
    alert($(this).text())
})
```

here is also a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7cqxK/)